# Modifying a certain field and variable in a file

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed

I'm looking forward in fixing the format of a database and allowing a user to input to what exact field he would like to modify in the database and modify the said amount using sed. To further explain the dilemma.

Let's say I have a hidden file named `.cart` which contains

`0011   Fish Tuna Eyeballs  2   80  160
0023    Fugu Fish Cream 3   360  1080
0035    Human Hair      5   2000 10000
0033    Stargazey Fish Pie  7   270 1890`

The 1st field is the product ID, 2nd field is the name, 3rd is the quantity, 4th is it's original price and 5th is the total price

1st problem: I'm having troubles with formatting. All 5 columns there are just pasted all together with \t as a delimiter and If you can notice the dislocation of the 2nd row and the 3rd row it's due to the item name. I'd like to fix this problem however i'm not sure where to start. Shortening the item name is not a possible option. (I'm having problems here probably because I cannot format pasted items?)

2nd problem: I would like to allow a user input to select what item they would like to modify I can easily do this by

`read -number
cat .cart | grep $number > .modifyme`

Which then gives us a hidden file called .modify me which we'll work on with the 3rd problem.

3rd problem: Modifying it's quantity (which is the 3rd field) by allowing a user input again to determine what it would be changed in to.

Now that we have `.modifyme` and just assuming that the user input in the 2nd problem is 0023 which gives us the content of `.modifyme` to be:

`0023   Fugu Fish Cream 3 360 1080`

I would like to allow again the user to modify the quantity (3rd field) with the input that they would enter.

I'm very open to any suggestions that you may have in order to solve the 3 problems above. The important thing here is to allow the user to input what item they would like to modify through the product id (1st field) and change it's quantity (3rd field) which is then multiplied to the original price (4th field) to obtain the total price (5th field).

Thank you so much! Much help is appreciated!

Comment: Clarify in what way having your fields tab delimited is a problem. Is it just for displaying to  a user? If so you could use `column -s$'\t' -t file` so it displays with all fields aligned without actually messing up the field separation in your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are against a tab delimited file. That seems very appropriate for this type of usage.

Just the same though, here's a quick 3 line script that will take a product id from a user, a qty from a user, and update the file (3rd and 5th) column using awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

#get the product id
read -p "Product ID: " productid

#get the new price
read -p "Qty: " qty

#update the record in the file
awk -F"\t" -v "prodid=$productid" -v "qty=$qty" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1==prodid { $3=qty; $5=( qty * $4 ) }{print $0}' .cart > .cart.tmp && mv -f .cart.tmp .cart
```

This should give enough direction to build from here. The big hairy parts are:

1. Shell variables are passed into awk via the awk `-v` flag.
2. We are splitting the file up into fields using a tab `/t` delim on the `-F` flag
3. We are specifying that we want the output field seperate to also be tab `OFS=FS`
4. We are testing the first field to see if it's the product id inputed by the user `$1 == prodid`
5. At the end we are redirecting the awk output back to a tmp file, then moving the tmp file on top of the existing `.cart` file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use your answer and see if it fits my script later on. Modify my logic if I have to but this is a big help! Thank you so much.